# grep range of numbers in a text file

Tags: bash, shell, grep, zsh

I have following text in a text file

```
$ cat test
20180618:
20180619:
20180620:
20180621:
20180622:
20180623:
20180624:
```

I have tried to grep with the range of numbers like below,

```
$ grep 201806{19..21} test
grep: 20180619: No such file or directory
grep: 20180620: No such file or directory
grep: 20180621: No such file or directory
```

I'm getting above error on both ZSH and bash. 
It seems grep taking the search string as files.

I have tried the another way:

```
$ grep 201806* test       
zsh: no matches found: 201806*
```

I am getting that error only on ZSH.
What is the right way to use `*` in ZSH and how can I tell grep to grep range of numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep 201806{19..21} test
```

is expanded by the shell to:

```
grep 20180619 20180620 20180621 test
```

Which `grep` understands as looking for `20180619` inside the 3 files, `20180620`, `20180621` and `test`.

If you change it to:

```
grep -e201806{19..21} test
```

Then that's expanded to:

```
grep -e20180619 -e20180620 -e20180621 test
```

Which gives 3 `e`xpressions for `grep` to search for in `test`.

Or you can do:

```
printf '%s\n' 201806{19..21} | grep -f - test
```

Where we pass the expressions as a number of lines of input to `grep` (with some implementations, you may need `/dev/stdin` in place of `-`).

With `zsh` specifically, you can also make it:

```
numbers=({19..21} 25 31)
grep -E "201801(${(j:|:)numbers})" test
```

Where we use the `(j:|:)` parameter expansion flag to join the array elements with `|` (the extended regular expression alternation operator) so it can be used as an ERE.

Or you could tie that array to a regexp scalar with:

```
$ typeset -T re numbers '|'
$ numbers=({19..21} 25 31)
$ echo $re
19|20|21|25|31
```

While regular expressions usually don't have number range matching capabilities, `zsh` patterns (which with `extendedglob` are functionally equivalent to regular expressions) do with the `<x-y>` operator (only for sequences of decimal digits):

```
print -rl -- ${(M)${(f)"$(<test)"}:#*201806<19-21>*}
```

Comment: +1 for grep -e201806{19..21} test.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, `grep` only treats its *first* argument as a regular expression by default.

This means that

```
grep {1..9} file
```

which expands to

```
grep 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 file
```

would invoke `grep` with `1` as the expression to match in the other operands, and that these other operands would be expected to be filenames.

Your other command:

```
grep 201806* test
```

This would try to match `201806*` as a filename globbing pattern.  You have no files whose names start with `201806` in the current directory so the `zsh` shell fails to expand the pattern and gives you the error message `no matches found`.

In other Bourne-like shells, if the pattern hadn't matched any filenames, it would have remained unexpanded and used as the regular expression with `grep`.  The expression `201806*`, when taken as a regular expression, matches `20180` followed by zero or more `6` characters, e.g. `2018066666`.

Instead, you may want to construct a regular expression to match your range:

```
grep -E '201806(19|20|21)' test
```

or

```
grep -E '201806(19|2[01])' test
```

The `-E` is needed to have `grep` understand `|` (alternation) in the expression (this alternation makes it an extended regular expression).

---

You could also construct a regular expression from a brace expansion:

```
set -- {19..21}
re=$( IFS='|'; printf '201806(%s)' "$*" )

grep -E "$re" test
```

This would first set the positional parameters, `$1`, `$2` and `$3`, to the wanted numbers in the range.  The variable `re` would then be set to `201806(%s)` where `printf` would replace `%s` with these numbers delimited by `|`.

The `grep` call would use `201806(19|20|21)` as the regular expression.

Comment: Or it could be done with a newline separated list of fixed strings maybe? i.e. `printf '%s\n' 201806{19..21} | grep -Ff- test`

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, but I _think_ you have to use `/dev/stdin` as the input file name, unless your `grep` interprets `-` as standard input.

Comment: It does - I didn't realize others didn't :(

Answer (score 2):

unquoted strings are interpreted by the shell before command is executed, in your case, the command you tried would be expanded to `grep 20180619 20180620 20180621 test`

```
$ echo grep 201806{19..21} test
grep 20180619 20180620 20180621 test
```

One workaround is to specify regular expression alternation:

```
$ grep -E '201806(19|20|21)' test
20180619:
20180620:
20180621:
```

You can construct a numeric range with regular expressions, but it is not easy. See https://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html for details

Another option is to use `awk`

```
$ awk -F: '$1>=20180619 && $1<=20180621' ip.txt
20180619:
20180620:
20180621:
```

Here, we split the line on `:` and then compare the first field `$1` with range required

Answer (score 1):

1. *POSIX* shell (no `bash`) with utils:

   ```
   seq 20180618 20180624 | grep -f - test
   ```
2. [`numgrep`](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/):

   ```
   numgrep '/20180618..20180624/' < test
   ```

Comment: (just to clear some possible confusion, note that neither `seq` nor `numgrep` are POSIX commands).